# doctrine symfony2 Error: Class Cocina\ComprasBundle\Entity\Productos has no association named proveedores

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm modifying CRUD generated by doctrine in symfony 2.8. I have 2 tables (proveedores(providers) and productos(products)) with a relation 1:n. 
I want show through index action the complete list of products with their providers that it owns.
What I try is create a DQL sentence that joins the 2 tables in the result and then manipulate it with twig.
When I try to access to index, I get the error mentioned.

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 75 near 'x ': Error: Class
>   Cocina\ComprasBundle\Entity\Productos has no association named
>   proveedores
>
> [2/2] QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 75 near 'x ':
>   Error: Class Cocina\ComprasBundle\Entity\Productos has no association
>   named proveedores
>
> [1/2] QueryException: SELECT p,x FROM ComprasBundle:Productos p JOIN
>   p.proveedores x

I have revised another similar threads over here but I have no found solution.
I have checked too clearing all the doctrine caches and symfony cache but nothing.
Thanks for the answers.

ENTITY PROVEEDORES

```
namespace Cocina\ComprasBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Proveedores
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="proveedores")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Cocina\ComprasBundle\Repository\ProveedoresRepository")
 */
class Proveedores
{
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
...
}
```

ENTITY PRODUCTOS

namespace Cocina\ComprasBundle\Entity;

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Productos
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="productos")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Cocina\ComprasBundle\Repository\ProductosRepository")
 */
class Productos
{
/**
 * @var integer $idProveedor
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Proveedores")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_proveedor_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $idProveedor;

...
}
```

PRODUCTOS REPOSITORY

```
namespace Cocina\ComprasBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * ProductosRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class ProductosRepository extends EntityRepository
{
public function findListaProductos()
{
    $em=$this->getEntityManager();
    $consulta=$em->createQuery('
            SELECT p,x
            FROM ComprasBundle:Productos p 
            JOIN p.proveedores x            
            ');
    return $consulta->getResult();
}
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
namespace Cocina\ComprasBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use Cocina\ComprasBundle\Entity\Productos;
use Cocina\ComprasBundle\Form\ProductosType;

/**
 * Productos controller.
 *
 */
class ProductosController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Lists all Productos entities.
 *
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    //$productos = $em->getRepository('ComprasBundle:Productos')->findAll();
    $productos=$em->getRepository('ComprasBundle:Productos')->findListaProductos()->getResult();

    return $this->render('ComprasBundle:productos:index.html.twig', array(
        'productos' => $productos,
    ));
}
```

[RELATIONSHIP SCHEMA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g56dd.png)

Comment: In the class `Productos`  rename the attribute `$idProveedor` with `$proveedores`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Entity Productos the relation is named `idProveedor` instead of `proveedores`. So try this query:

```
public function findListaProductos()
{
    $em=$this->getEntityManager();
    $consulta=$em->createQuery('
            SELECT p,x
            FROM ComprasBundle:Productos p 
            JOIN p.idProveedor x            
            ');
    return $consulta->getResult();
}
```

Hope this helps

NB: As previous comment probably is better renaming the relation as expected in your query as proveedores

Comment: yeah... this was the problem. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not joining correctly. It should be something like: FROM tablename INNER JOIN othertablename ON tablename.someid =  othertablename.someid.

However, with doctrine you don't need to do that. You can just call a function from your entity.

See [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#fetching-related-objects).
You should generate your getters and setters. (something like php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle).

Then you can just query your productos (pseudocode not tested).

```
     $productos = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('ComprasBundle:Productos')
    ->findAll() or fetchAll();
```

And then you have your proveedores in your objects. It probably returns an array of objects. Pseudocode:

```
      $firstproductprovidername  = $productos[0]->getProveedores()->getName();
      $firstproductproviderid  = $productos[0]->getProveedores()->getId();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Setters and getters are in the entities but I had to cut the code because it was so long. I can use findAll() without problems and I had no problems using data fixtures with the model, in fact filling the databases with the data fixtures it recognizes the associations. If you see the controller, you can see a commented line that works fine and it includes a findAll() but only on a entity. I need recover the data of the two tables because i need to show all products with its providers